# How to style one item from main navigation?

Tags: php, menus, navigation

I am trying to style one element of my navigation. To display the whole navigation I am using:

```
          <?php 
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
        ?>
```

It returns 4 main menu items. Only the last item should be positioned at the right. The rest should stay at the left. I checked the id of the desired item and tryed to style it separetly using:

```
li#menu-item-258.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page menu-item-258{color:red;}
```

For some reason it does not work. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily make the text of the last item right position with:

```
ul#nav li:last-child span {
   text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: In my case this also worked: li#menu-item-259 a{float:right;}
li#menu-item-258 a{margin-left: 140px;}

Comment: This is not the right method !